# Bound expressions inside a condition in a cond block in Elixir?

Tags: conditional-statements, elixir

Is there any way to have multiple bound expressions in a condition in a `cond` block similar to:

```
cond do
   a = 1; a * 2 == 2 -> "Yes"
end
```

?
I guess it would be possible if there were something in Elixir like "let in" binding expressions as in Haskell:

```
let a = 1 in a * 2
```

**Update**
In the case below I'd like to bind the `String.replace` expression to a variable to increase readability (I could of course do it outside the `cond` which isn't an optimal solution for obvious reasons). The condition checks if the `input` is upper case only (apart from non-alphabetic characters) and is taken from an exercism.io challenge:

```
      String.upcase(String.replace(input, ~r/[^A-Za-z]/, "")) == String.replace(input, ~r/[^A-Za-z]/, "") and String.length(String.replace(input, ~r/[^A-Za-z]/, "")) > 0 -> "Whoa, chill out!"
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to acheive with that?

Comment: In the condition there could for example be a recurring expression that for readability and other reasons you would want to bind to a variable. I'll update the question with an example taken from a challenge on exercism.io.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To directly answer the first question, the answer is yes. Your original code:

```
cond do
   a = 1; a * 2 == 2 -> "Yes"
end
```

Is parsed as:

```
cond do
   a = 1
   a * 2 == 2 -> "Yes"
end
```

Because `;` means the end of the whole expression. In case you want to include multiple expressions, use parens:

```
cond do
   (a = 1; a * 2 == 2) -> "Yes"
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your original question, I think there's nothing wrong with extracting a variable here:

```
def myfun(input) do
  sanitized = String.replace(input, ~r/[^A-Za-z]/, "")
  cond do
    String.upcase(sanitized) == sanitized and String.length(sanitized) > 0 -> "Whoa, chill out!"
    true -> "Good job"
  end
end
```

You could also use the match operator `=` inside the pattern, more specifically you can use it in place of the first occurrence, but I think it is uglier and harder to read:

```
def myfun(input) do
  cond do
    String.upcase(sanitized = String.replace(input, ~r/[^A-Za-z]/, "")) == sanitized and String.length(sanitized) > 0 -> "Whoa, chill out!"
    true -> "Good job"
  end
end
```

However your code can be improved by closely looking at the comparisons you are doing. To match the condition, the `input` string must consist of only uppercase and non-alphabetic characters, containing at least one uppercase character. Since you are already using regexes, here's one that will match all of this in a single check:

```
\A[^a-z]*[A-Z][^a-z]*\z
```

Explanation:

- `\A` and `\z` match string boundaries, the entire string must fulfill the condition
- `[^a-z]*` zero or more non-lowercase characters, followed by
- `[A-Z]` an uppercase character somewhere in the string, followed by
- `[^a-z]*` zero or more non-lowercase characters

Code:

```
def myfun(input) do
  cond do
    Regex.match?(~r/\A[^a-z]*[A-Z][^a-z]*\z/, input) -> "Whoa, chill out!"
    true -> "Good job"
  end
end
```

Comment: Tough call but I think José's answer is closer to what I was looking for. Anyway thank you for your answer, it was enlightening!

Comment: Hey no worries, this is not a contest ;-)

Comment: I am glad Patrick asked what you were trying to achieve because otherwise I would have asked it too. :D